# Best approach when renaming a well rooted model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Lets say I am modifying an already existing web application and I want to rename my `People` model to `User`. I have about 100 pages that reference the `People` model, I would have to change that to reference `User`. I have made those changes, but I must have forgotten a couple. Is there a way to automated this process?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you should use testing to avoid such problems. But, if there's no tests already, you can use any text editor to search in all project files. For example, in Sublime text you can use "Ctrl+Shift+F" or "Cdm+Shift+F" combination.

Comment: Testing was the first thing that came to mind and I have written some RSPEC, but mainly for models. I was just putting some feelers out there to see if there was a more efficient, less time consuming way to go about it. Thanks for your input!